# Removing someone who has taged themselves as working for your page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

You see I sort of have an issue with a former employee who is still listed as working for me on his facebook profile. I would like to know if it is possible for me to remove that tag from his profile. Contacting him and asking nicely is not an option.

Comment: not possible to acomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If contacting him and asking nicely (or by force) is not an option, you can't remove that tag by any legal means.

If you could, it would mean a violation of his privacy and a free choice. Even if its a lie, he did not anyhow violate (willingly or unwillingly) any ToS rules, simply because there is not such a rule stating that any information on the internet can't be a lie.